# How to group each count value of different condition in the same table into 1 table

Tags: mysql

i have 1 Inner join table

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as dirtyRoom FROM t_room INNER JOIN t_room_type ON t_room.roomType = t_room_type.code WHERE status = 'sPVDirty'   output :  dirtyRoom : 13


SELECT COUNT(*) as readyRoom FROM t_room INNER JOIN t_room_type ON t_room.roomType = t_room_type.code WHERE status = 'sPVReady'   output : readyRoom : 33

SELECT COUNT(*) as maintenanceRoom FROM t_room INNER JOIN t_room_type ON t_room.roomType = t_room_type.code WHERE status = 'sPVMaint' output : maintenanceRoom : 4
```

I WANT to group each count value of different condition into 1 table with 3 column that display each each value

**output :** 
Table1

```
 dirtyRoom             readyRoom           maintenanceRoom
    13                     33                     4
```

how to do that?

Comment: SELECT SUM(IF(status='sPVDirty',1,0)) as dirtyRoom,SUM(IF(status='sPVReady',1,0)) as readyRoom,SUM(IF(status='sPVMaint',1,0)) as maintenanceRoom FROM t_room INNER JOIN t_room_type ON t_room.roomType = t_room_type.code;

Comment: ok thx.. it's work
btw what is 1, 0 in SUM(IF(status='sPVDirty',1,0)) function meaning ?

Comment: If the statement is true add 1, otherwise add 0.  It is called a ternary operator and follows the format: IF(<CONDITION>,<TRUE VALUE>,<FALSE VALUE>).  Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(IF(status='sPVDirty',status,0)) As DirtyRoom,
       COUNT(IF(status='sPVReady',status,0)) As ReadyRoom,
       COUNT(IF(status='sPVMaint',status,0)) As MaintenanceRoom 
FROM t_room INNER JOIN t_room_type ON t_room.roomType = t_room_type.code
```

*Or:*

```
SELECT SUM(IF(status='sPVDirty',1,0)) As DirtyRoom,
       SUM(IF(status='sPVReady',1,0)) As ReadyRoom,
       SUM(IF(status='sPVMaint',1,0)) As MaintenanceRoom 
FROM t_room INNER JOIN t_room_type ON t_room.roomType = t_room_type.code
```

So your Output Will Be

```
+------------+------------+--------------------+
| DirtyRoom  | ReadyRoom  |MaintenanceRoom     |
+------------+------------+--------------------+
| 13         | 33         |4                   |
+------------+------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT 
    IF(status = 'sPVDirty', count(status), 0) as dirtyRoom,
    IF(status = 'sPVReady', count(status), 0) as readyRoom,
    IF(status = 'sPVMaint', count(status), 0) as maintenanceRoom,
FROM t_room INNER JOIN t_room_type ON t_room.roomType = t_room_type.code
```